# Getting an implicit parameterized type in a for comprehension, in Scala 3

Tags: scala, types, for-comprehension, scala-3

A Scala 3 syntax question here.
I feel like there's not enough documentation around this yet.

How do you fetch an implicit value in a for comprehension, when its type is parameterized?

```scala
for
  o               <- Option("line just to make for comprehension start")
  given Int       = 2
  a               = implicitly[Int] // error: no implicit argument of type Int was found for parameter e of method implicitly in object Predef
  given List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
  b               = implicitly[List[Int]] // error: no implicit argument of type List[Int] was found for parameter e of method implicitly in object Predef
yield ()
```

**Edit:**

But if I insert a dummy line in between the declaration and the usage, it works:

```scala
for
  o               <- Option("line just to make for comprehension start")
  given List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
  p               <- Option("dummy")
  b               = implicitly[List[Int]] // works
yield ()
```

Comment: Can you add error text?

Comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/15526